# Upload file in a specified google drive folder with google drive API and using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I need to Upload files to a specified Google drive with Google drive API and JavaScript. Do I need to know belong method can be used for that or what can be used for that? If this function can be used please tell how to change this code.

```
    function retrieveAllFiles(callback) {
    var retrievePageOfFiles = function(request, result) {
     request.execute(function(resp) {  
      result = result.concat(resp.items);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageToken': nextPageToken
        });
        retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }


     var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
     retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, [Upload]);
}
```

Comment: Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) on how to upload files in the Drive Api, then you can now insert the files into a specific folder by following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder). Note that in inserting a file in a specific folder, you must use the parents property.

Comment: @kendiNov, thank you for giving comment for this.but I cannot understand guide. I will try it again. if you have any example code. please send me that for getting an idea about that?